# Unix step won't complete

Tags: unix

First, I am not a Unix scripter, but have been tasked to have the step below to check for the file size.  If it is greater than 0, then it will continue to process that file.

However, if its 0, it will echo "Skip it - NO DATA IN THE dnt_pln_inconj.dat FILE"

Problem is when I run this step, it only gets as far as "Received file with data -  Continue"

How can I make it continue processing if the file size is greater than 0? What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be awesome.

```
#Step 12: Verify pln proc inconjunction
step_num=$((step_num+1))
echo "stepnum $step_num: Verify pln proc inconjunction"

if [[ $last_step -eq $step_num ]]
then
  if [[ -s ${source_dir}/${file} ]]
  then
    echo "Received file with data -  Continue"

    $scriptdir/dental_script/dnt_verify_counts.sh dnt_pln_inconj.dat PLN-130
    ret_val=$?
    if [[ $ret_val -ne 0 ]]
    then
      next_step_num=$((step_num+1))
      echo $next_step_num > $logdir/$scriptname"_"step_num.log
      exit $step_num
    fi
  else
    echo "Skip it - NO DATA IN THE dnt_pln_inconj.dat FILE"
  fi
  last_step=$((last_step+1))
else
  echo "Skip it"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what dnt_verify_counts.sh script is doing. 
In your code line:

`ret_val=$?`

is checking for exit code of previous command - which is dnt_verify_counts.sh with parameters. I think it doesn't return file size..
If you want to check file size, play with 'du' utility for example, which gives you size of given file, e.g.:

`du /path/to/dnt_pln_inconj.dat`

and then, cut given data with `cut`, to return only size part; line:

`$(du /path/to/dnt_pln_inconj.dat | cut -f 1 -)`

will return given file size which you can use in your if - then - else block.conditions checking.

Comment: The dnt_verify_counts.sh is checking for existence of the dnt_counts.dat file and if its populated (its always populated). The dnt_counts.dat is simply a file that contains the record counts of certain files.